# How to run reactbootstrap with babel?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to run [this](https://codepen.io/enriquemontalvo/pen/mEjrXp) sample in my Webpack/ReactJS setup. I also did:

```
npm react-bootstrap
```

This is my component:

```
import React from 'react'
const {
    Navbar,
    Nav,
    NavItem,
    NavDropdown,
    MenuItem
} = ReactBootstrap;

export class ModalTest extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Navbar>
                <Navbar.Header>
                    <Navbar.Brand>
                        <a href="#">React-Bootstrap</a>
                    </Navbar.Brand>
                </Navbar.Header>
                <Nav>
                    <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">Link</NavItem>
                    <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">Link</NavItem>
                    <NavDropdown eventKey={3} title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                        <MenuItem eventKey={3.1}>Action</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem eventKey={3.2}>Another action</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem eventKey={3.3}>Something else here</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem divider />
                        <MenuItem eventKey={3.3}>Separated link</MenuItem>
                    </NavDropdown>
                </Nav>
            </Navbar>
        );
    }
}

export default ModalTest
```

But when I run my project I get:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ReactBootstrap is not defined
```

How can I fix this or do I need more references?

Comment: Did you install it with `npm i react-boostrap`?

Comment: yes I sure did an npm install

Comment: Can you show more code?

Comment: Here you go buddy

Comment: You didn't import it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import your `react-bootstrap` components like

```
import {Navbar, Nav,NavItem, NavDropdown, MenuItem} from  'react-bootstrap';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to import your react-bootstrap components like this.

```
import {Navbar, Nav,NavItem, NavDropdown, MenuItem} from  'react-bootstrap';
```